# How to write SQL ...where mytable.somedate from today is older that 30 days

Tags: sql, db2

How to write in SQL `...where mytable.somedate from today is older that 30 days`. I am using db2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE somedate < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 30 DAYS
```